# Replacing custom text with a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a feature, when a user comments and makes a special reference I want to replace that reference with a react component. Use this as an example:

> This is my first post on this app, check out these 2 games @apps_blackjack & @apps_weather.

The keyword to look for in a string is anything that starts with `"@apps_"` and then get the second keyword `"blackjack"` or `"weather"` and returns a component while passing down that variable to the component.

This is what I'm expecting:

```
<Link className='post_link' to={props.app}>
  Link
</Link>
```

The `{props.app}` variable would be blackjack or weather in this case. The final outcome would be:

```
This is my first post on this app, check out these 2 games 
<Link className='post_link' to='blackjack'>
  Link
</Link>
 & 
<Link className='post_link' to='weather'>
  Link
</Link>
```

I'm thinking about using `string.replace()` but am not exactly sure how to implement it as it is much more complicated since we need to also preserve the keyword that comes after the @apps_ keyword.

This is somehow similar to the feature that Facebook uses in the messenger app to highlight user names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first split by the mentions, then match the mentions with the same regex. Next, you would "interlace" them together with `flatMap`. Then you can render the final array of text and elements. Here I've used a regular anchor element that directs you to a Google search of the mention, but the idea should translate to your real code as well.

```js
function App() {
    const text = "This is my first post on this app, check out these 2 games @apps_blackjack & @apps_weather.";
    const mention = /@apps_\w+/g;
    
    const splitted = text.split(mention);
    const mentions = text.match(mention);
    
    const together = splitted.flatMap((text, index) => index < mentions.length ? [text, <a href={`https://www.google.com/search?q=${mentions[index].slice("@apps_".length)}`}>{mentions[index]}</a>] : [text]);
    
    return <div>{together}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<duv id="root"></div>
```